# Como comparar elementos de dos arrays?

Tags: php, apache

Buenas, mi problema es que no he podido comparar un elemento entre dos arrays.
lo que busco es que se compare si el elemento del array2 esta en el array1 y que me imprima ese elemento y si no esta que imprima no tiene significado.

Se trata que si el color favorito de la persona esta el significado en el array de color, imprima el significado de lo contrario imprima que no se encontro significado.

He intentado de varias formas pero no me imprime nada.. Se le agradecería una pronta respuesta

**Este es el codigo:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Unidad 2 -Ejercicio 4</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
      content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

</head>
<body>   
<?php  

//se crea un array multidimensional
$personas=array('Juan gabriel'=>array(
  'direccion'=>'Calle 7# 8-25',
  'telefono'=>'31789456',
  'Fecha de cumpleaños'=>'14/09/1992',
  'color favorito'=>'verde'
),

                'Andrea martinez'=>array(
                  'direccion'=>'Calle 10# 9-75',
                  'telefono'=>'31789456',
                  'Fecha de cumpleaños'=>'28/06/1994',
                  'color favorito'=>'blanco'
                ),

                'Nancy peña'=>array('direccion'=>'Av 5 #23-58 Sur',
                                    'telefono'=>'31789456',
                                    'Fecha de cumpleaños'=>'2/02/1991',
                                    'color favorito'=>'azul'),

               );

$colores=array('blanco'=>'pureza',
              'verde'=>'esperanza',)


?>


<br>    <br>
<br>

    <!--    se crea una tabla donde mostraran los datos-->
<table widtch="60%" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>  
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Nombres</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Direccion</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Telefono</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Fecha de cumpleaños</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Color favorito</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Significado</th>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  //se recorre el array 
  foreach($personas as $nombre=>$informacion){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $nombre . '</td>';
    foreach($informacion as $info){
      echo '<td>' . $info . '</td>';

    }
      foreach($personas as $signicado){
        if (in_array($signicado, $colores)){
          echo '<td>' . $colores .'</td>';
        }
      }

    //          foreach ($personas as $cuales)
   //          {
  //            $igual=array_search($cuales, $colores);
 //            if($igual)
//            { 
//          echo '<td>' . $colores[$igual]. '</td>';
//            }
//          }

//          foreach($colores as $significado){
//            $significado=array_intersect_assoc($personas, $colores)
//              echo '<td>' . $significado . '</td>';
//            }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en los datos que le estas pasando a `in_array`. Le estas pasando como `aguja` una *matriz asociativa* (`$significado`), cuando los soportados para la `aguja` son un `arreglo (plano) o una cadena`.

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
<table widtch="60%" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>  
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Nombres</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Direccion</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Telefono</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Fecha de cumpleaños</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Color favorito</th>
    <th bgcolor="#449742">Significado</th>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  //se recorre el array 
  foreach($personas as $nombre=>$informacion){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $nombre . '</td>';
    foreach($informacion as $info){
      echo '<td>' . $info . '</td>';

    }
    // Si el color favorito esta en el arreglo $colores
    $significado = '&nbsp;'; //Entidad HTML del espacio ( )
    if(isset($colores[$informacion['color favorito']])) {
        $significado = $colores[$informacion['color favorito']];
    }
    echo '<td>' . $significado .'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder pero mira que me sale el siguiente error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sena\ejercicio_4.php on line 74"  He analizado y no encuentro el error.

Comment: Gracias, faltaba el if y los paréntesis no había captado. Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. Me funciono!